# Processbuilder output as it is executing

Tags: java, shell

I would like the output of a shell command to go to a textArea in my java program as the shell command executes rather than after it has completed.

Current code that waits until process is complete and then shows the output:

```
ProcessBuilder builder = new ProcessBuilder("shell_command.sh");

builder.redirectErrorStream(true);

try {
    Process p = builder.start();
    String s;
    BufferedReader stdout = new BufferedReader (
        new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));

    while ((s = stdout.readLine()) != null) {
        logPanel.addText(s + "\r\n"); // adds text to a textArea
    }

    System.out.println("Exit value: " + p.waitFor());
    p.getInputStream().close();
    p.getOutputStream().close();
    p.getErrorStream().close();
} catch (Exception ex) {
    ex.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: Are you running this on the UI thread?

Comment: Yes. I think I see your point though. I suppose I shouldn't be.

Comment: For better help sooner, post a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/). If this app. is based on either Swing or AWT, it will be important not to block the Event Dispatch Thread.

Answer (score 0):

In UI thread...

```
(new Thread(new ShellCommand(logPanel) ) ).start();
```

New Class...

```
class ShellCommand implements Runnable {

    LogPanel logPanel; // textArea

    ShellCommand(LogPanel logPanel) {
        this.logPanel = logPanel;
    }

    public void run() {

        try {
            ProcessBuilder builder = new ProcessBuilder("shell_command.sh");

            builder.redirectErrorStream(true);

            Process p = builder.start();
            String s;
            BufferedReader stdout = new BufferedReader(new 
                InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));
            while ((s = stdout.readLine()) != null) {
                logPanel.addText(s + "\r\n");
            }

            System.out.println("Exit value: " + p.waitFor());
            p.getInputStream().close();
            p.getOutputStream().close();
            p.getErrorStream().close();

            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Done", "Message",
                 JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);

            } catch (Exception ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}
```